# Conversion of URDF to SDF source code

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have noticed that while converting robot description from URDF to SDF file, some parameters are lost, even though they are set in accordance with the documentation. I was looking through the Gazebo source code but can't find the file where the conversion from URDF to SDF happens. Can you point me to it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24162/conversion-of-urdf-to-sdf-source-code/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Found it in the sdformat package at `src/parser_urdf.cc`.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0